# Check if value in A is unique to B

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have a tab on which I run multiple checks with a VBA 'If' statement. I want to add something that checks this, but I can't seem to figure out an easy way to do so. My file looks like:

```
     A           B
   1 Yellow     Banana
   2 Yellow     Banana
   3 Blue       Banana
   4 Red        Tomato
   5 Orange     Tomato
   6 Green      Pear
   7 Green      Pepper
```

For instance: I have to check to see if every fruit in B that is Banana, then the colour in A is Yellow.

Banana can also have another color/or a second one (purple for instance) but then purple can't be used for other fruits in B anymore. (These colors are just examples and it has nothing do do with fruit and colors.)

**TLDR:** Once a color/value from A has been linked to a certain fruit/value in B that color/value in A cannot be used for another fruit/value anymore.

Is there an easy way to do this in VBA in my current 'If' statement?

Comment: Are you able to create a table of what the items in column A should be compared to items in Column B, then a comparison could be accomplished.

Comment: How do you mean? The data is on a tab that i cannot alter. But i could of course copy/paste some stuff into a new empty tab if that is what you mean.

Comment: So I'm guessing that *Pepper* is the anomaly 'cause *Green* has already been allocated to *Pear*. A simple walk through the pairs with a [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) to find matching colors that do not match the fruit should do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using Collections in VBA?

If not use two collections, one containing 'values' and one for 'fruits'.

Option 1) Starting off with all unique values in the 'fruits' and 'values' collections, then remove from them.

Here is some example psuedo code I haven't tested.

```
Dim vals As Collection
Dim fruits As Collection

Private Sub Init_Collections()
    Set vals = New Collection
    Set fruits = New Collection

    'Add all unique values
    vals.Add("Purple")
    vals.Add("Red")

    'Add all unique fruits
    fruits.Add("Orange")
    fruits.Add("Apple")
End Sub

Private Sub CheckPairs()
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim row As Integer
    Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Call Init_Collections()

    row = 1
    while(Sheet.Cells(row,1).Value <> "")
        if(fruits.Contains(Sheet.Cells(row,2).Value) AND _
           vals.Contains(Sheet.Cells(row,1).Value)) Then
            'Success - Pair doesn't exist
            fruits.Remove(Sheet.Cells(row,2).Value)
            vals.Remove(Sheet.Cells(row,1).Value)
        else
            'Fail - Pair one of the values or fruits is already being used
        end if
        row = row + 1
    wend
End Sub
```

Option 2) You start off with two empty collections and keep adding to them.

Here is some example psuedo code I haven't tested.

```
Private Sub CheckPairs()
    Dim vals As New Collection
    Dim fruits As New Collection
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim row As Integer
    Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    row = 1
    while(Sheet.Cells(row,1).Value <> "")
        if(fruits.Contains(Sheet.Cells(row,2).Value) OR _
           vals.Contains(Sheet.Cells(row,1).Value)) Then
            'Fail - Pair one of the values or fruits is already being used
        else
            'Success - These items don't exist, add them to their collections
            fruits.Add(Sheet.Cells(row,2).Value)
            vals.Add(Sheet.Cells(row,1).Value)
        end if
        row = row + 1
    wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a macro to check your values and highlight any cell which's content was previously to another fruit. Select your range of colors and fruits (the two columns) then run the macro.

```
Sub TestFruitsAndColors()
    Dim d As Object, cell As Range
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each cell In Selection.Columns(1).Cells
        If Not d.Exists(cell.Value) Then
            d.Add cell.Value, cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        ElseIf d.Item(cell.Value) <> cell.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
            cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @Jeeped thanks for the remark. Modified the macro to use late binding and avoid the need for this.

Comment: I just hate it when I get code from someone that requires a library and I don't know *which* library! :)

Comment: @Elmer, I dont have a clue about your IF statement. but you can take the idea: First, fill the dictionary by doing a pass on the range, then do your if against the dictionary's content.

Comment: Does that work or need I edit it and show the details?

Comment: English is not my first language. So this will highlight the "colors" that were already allocated to a different fruit previously? So I can see which ones are wrongfully assigned to a second piece of fruit?

Comment: It will highlight Cell A7 in your example, and generally any color that is already used by another fruit.

Comment: Thanks. It's almost 1 AM here. Will test this tomorrow. Seems like this would work.

Answer (score 0):

If you walk down the fruits looking for previous matches to the current color with non-matching fruits you can easily identify the latter non-matches.

```
Sub dup_frute()
    Dim frt As Range, bgnfrt As Range, endfrt As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet5")
        Set bgnfrt = .Range("B1")
        Set endfrt = .Cells(Rows.Count, bgnfrt.Column).End(xlUp)
        For Each frt In .Range(bgnfrt, endfrt)
            If CBool(Application.CountIfs( _
              .Range(bgnfrt, frt), "<>" & frt.Value2, _
              .Range(bgnfrt, frt).Offset(0, -1), frt.Offset(0, -1).Value2)) Then
                Debug.Print frt.Value2                'Pepper
                Debug.Print frt.Offset(0, -1).Value2  'Green
            End If
        Next frt
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This might work but i don't think I can use this in the IF statement I already have.

Comment: Yeah, you mentioned *'my current 'If' statement'* in your question but to date, there is no detail on it and my crystal ball is in the shop.

Comment: Sorry mate. I didn't explain it properly. I would ideally be able use it as a condition in an IF statement.  Hope I explained it correctly now. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function you can call from VBA to test the ranges:

```
Function Check(a As Range, b As Range) As String
    Dim i&, k&, s$, L$, R$, p, v
    v = Evaluate(a.Address & "&""|""&" & b.Address)
    s = Join(Application.Transpose(v), "|") & "|"
    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        k = 2: p = Split(v(i, 1), "|"): L = p(0): R = p(1)
        Do: k = InStr(k, s, L & "|")
            If k Then
                If Mid$(s, k + 1 + Len(L), Len(R) + 1) <> R & "|" Then: Check = L: Exit For
                k = k + 1
            End If
        Loop While k
    Next
End Function
```

That's it.

Here is how to call it:

```
Sub TestIt()

    s = Check([a1:a7], [b1:b7])

    If Len(s) Then
        s = s & " is matched with more than one value."
    Else
        s = "It's good."
    End If

    MsgBox s

End Sub
```

Comment: Will give this a try tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: @Elmer Did this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple formula.

Enter in C2 as shown and fill down.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,A2,B$2:B2,"<>" & B2)>0,"Error","OK")
```

[image]

Comment: While the `>0` does explain the logic behind the formula, it is unnecessary as **0** resolves to FALSE and anything that is not false is TRUE.